# how to make it to start up like this 'john@john:~/Desktop$ blah blah blah

Tags: command-line

When I start the Terminal I want it to start up like this `john@john:~/Desktop$ blah blah blah` without executing the command so I tried to do this `sh -c "cd ~/Desktop;blah blah blah; exec bash"` but it executed the command.

Comment: how did you do it? post an answer yourself!

Comment: There that's how i did it :D

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Okay i have found a way to do this, first you go to

Edit>Profile preferences>Title and Command

and in the 'Run a custom command instead of my shell' put this

```
sh -c "cd ~/Desktop; exec bash"
```

now open gpedit and type this script in:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho bash

expect "$ " 

send "put what ever you want here"

interact

exit
```

save that as a  `anything.sh`

then `chmod +x anything.sh`

and run the `anything.sh` with Terminal and you're all done! :D

Comment: I hope this helps people out :D